# How to change submit button name in HAML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am new to Haml and have a form with two submit buttons. To differentiate and handle them in the Controller every single button needs a name.

An example from HAML:

```
= program_form.submit I18n.t('texts.6OA')
```

appears in HTML as:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save Template">
```

but I want something like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="Button2" value="Save Template">
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
program_form.submit I18n.t('texts.60A'), name: 'Button2'
```

Comment: Thank you, forgot the ',' before name :). Now it's working!